# Django rendering {% csrf_token %} as string when I set innerHTML

Tags: javascript, python, html, django

I have a page in which I have created a modal. Now I'm creating form in the modal that can be generated dynamically on the basis of which button is clicked.

I have this JS function that sets the model content with form data.

```js
function openModal(askField, platformName) {
    const modal = document.getElementById("modal");
    const modalContent = modal.querySelector('.modal-content');
    modalContent.innerHTML = `
        <h2 class="m-2 text-xl font-semibold text-center">${platformName} Authorization</h2>
        <form class="p-2" method="post" action="/authorize/${platformName.toLowerCase()}">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <div class="p-3 border border-gray-500 rounded-lg">
                <div class="m-2 flex justify-start space-x-2">
                    <label class="font-bold" for="ask_field">${titleCase(askField.replace("_", " "))}</label>
                    <input class="border" id="ask_field" name="ask_field" required>
                </div>
                <div class="flex justify-between">
                    <button class="px-4 rounded-lg text-white transition ease-in-out delay-150 bg-red-600 hover:-translate-y-1 hover:scale-110 hover:bg-indigo-500 duration-300" onclick="closeModal()">
                        Close
                    </button>
                    <button class="px-4 rounded-lg text-white transition ease-in-out delay-150 bg-blue-500 hover:-translate-y-1 hover:scale-110 hover:bg-indigo-500 duration-300">
                        Authorize
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    `;
    modal.classList.remove('hidden');
}
```

This modal works successfully. The only problem is that when this `{% csrf_token %}` is not actually embedded into the page but it's rendering as a string.

[image]

I know as I'm adding this piece of HTML after the page is already rendered by the Django. That's why this is happening.

Is there any way that I can get this working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to manually set the value of the token by getting a cookie like so:

```
function getCookie(name) {
    let cookieValue = null;
    if (document.cookie && document.cookie !== '') {
        const cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
        for (let i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
            const cookie = cookies[i].trim();
            // Does this cookie string begin with the name we want?
            if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) === (name + '=')) {
                cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return cookieValue;
}
const csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken');
```

Or optionally:

```
{% csrf_token %}
<script>
const csrftoken = document.querySelector('[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').value;
</script>
```

This piece of [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/howto/csrf/#using-csrf-protection-with-ajax) might help

Comment: Thank you so much. Your solution works great. but it didn't resolve my problem. But still it helped me to get at a conclusion. I also did some research and came to the conclusion that in place of `{% csrf_token %}` while setting the innerHTML I have to replace this `{% csrf_token %}` from the string with `<input name="csrfmiddlewaretoken" value="${getCookie('csrftoken')}" hidden>` 

More can be followed here: https://www.stackhawk.com/blog/django-csrf-protection-guide/